# What do very high PACF values (>10) mean?

Tags: time-series, acf-pacf

I understand that PACF values are not supposed to exceed +/- 1. However a few data points show PACF values like 30 or 15. What do these values mean? Should I remove them from the dataset? And if I do, what should I replace these values with?

I'm using statsmodels/python for the pacf. Is there something wrong with the statsmodel function (most sources use R to calculate acf/pacf), my data or the method? (If I use 'ywmle' method it works fine, no values above 1)

[image]

Comment: ACF or PACF values cannot exceed $\pm1$ (since this is the correlation coefficient), so that must be a mistake.

Comment: Nope, I checked, and some lags show values higher than one using the statsmodels pacf in python.

Comment: Can you show us the data and plots?

Comment: try to figure out what "yule walker with bias correction in denominator for acovf" means mathematically. by default, i.e. without some altering of the denominator,  the absolute value of the pacf and acf has to be bounded by 1 by the cauchy schwarz inequality.

Comment: There is a numerical problem or instability in this method for lags that are large relative to the sample size. I have seen this also for different datasets, but don't know what the source of the numerical problem is.

Comment: Add method='ywm' like 

$\textit{pacf_values = sm.tsa.stattools.pacf(time_series, nlags=len(time_series)//7,method='ywm')
}$